# Crystal Enterpise 10 - Default NT Domain

Tags: authentication, crystal-reports

I am trying to change the Default NT Domain on our Crystal Enterpise Server setup. But everytime I try it I get this message:

Error

---

Error updating Windows NT authentication properties: NT Authentication failed to verify one or more of the mapped groups. If the problem persists, please delete and re-map into Crystal Enterprise the following group(s): S-1-5-21-1182020584-1628855901-1435325219-4772; S-1-5-21-1182020584-1628855901-1435325219-513

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an article with a guy that had a similar problem. If I read it correctly they were running in Mixed Mode using NT Authentication but had to go over to AD Authentication because there were no servers on their network set up to do NT Authentication. Read it over and see if it is similar.

http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=213580&sid=9c2ec166978ddf39bd27058fa3b5f472

This may be a completely different issue than the one you are having, but I figured I'd throw it out there. Hope it helps.